# Length of a fully filled array

Tags: c, strlen

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>    
int main(void)    
{
    char cp [5];
    cp[0]=1;
    cp[1]=1;
    cp[2]=1;
    cp[3]=1;
    cp[4]=1;
    printf("%lu\n", strlen(cp));
}
```

If I run this program, it displays 8.(wrong)
But if I`ll change array to more than [5] (example: [6] or [7]...) with the same number of array elements, it displays 5 (right).

Comment: you missed the null cgaracter required by strlen

Comment: arrays in C are unpredictable and highly dependent on the compiler. You should keep in mind that strlen always require to have \0 to determine the length of the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*strlen* return the number characters from the pointer you give up to a null character (not count), in your case you do not put a null character in your array, so *strlen* goes out of the array with an undefined behavior

for instance do

```
char cp [6];
cp[0]=1;
cp[1]=1;
cp[2]=1;
cp[3]=1;
cp[4]=1;
cp[5] = 0;
printf("%zu\n", strlen(cp));
```

also notice I changed the format, *strlen* returns a *size_t* the right format for it is *%zu*

---

out of that you put in your array characters having the code 1, that character is generally not writable, did you want '1' rather than 1 ?